# clipbucket Unknown encoder 'libfaac'

Tags: video, centos, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using CB script when i upload any video after uploading it give file to processing this my loge

> Started on 2013-09-06 20:23:00 - 2013 Sep 06
>
> Checking File ....
>   File : /home/admin/clip/files/conversion_queue/1378484580dae10.mkv
>   File Exists : Yes
>
> Preparing file...
>   format : matroska,webm
>   duration : 137.71
>   size : 10177263
>   bitrate : 577
>   video_width : 554
>   video_height : 312
>   video_wh_ratio : 1.775641025641
>   video_codec : h264
>   video_rate : 24.99455377242
>   video_bitrate : 483
>   video_color : N/A
>   audio_codec : aac
>   audio_bitrate : 91
>   audio_rate : 44100
>   audio_channels : stereo
>   path : /home/admin/clip/files/conversion_queue/1378484580dae10.mkv
>
> Converting Video
>   Conversion Command : /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i >/home/admin/clip/files/conversion_queue/1378484580dae10.mkv -f flv -vcodec libx264 -vpre >normal -r 25 -s 554x312 -aspect 1.775641025641 -vf pad=0:0:0:0:black -acodec libfaac -ab >128000 -ar 22050 /home/admin/clip/files/videos/1378484580dae10.flv 2> >/home/admin/clip/files/temp/137848458055c92.tmp
>
> Conversion Details
>
> ffmpeg version 0.9.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
>   built on May 11 2013 13:27:19 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
>   configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --shlibdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man >--enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable->postproc >--enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable->avisynth -->enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable->libopencore->amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora -->enable-libvorbis -->enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags='-O2 ->g -pipe -Wall -Wp,->D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer->size=4 -m32 >march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables' --disable-stripping
>   libavutil 51. 32. 0 / 51. 32. 0
>   libavcodec 53. 42. 4 / 53. 42. 4
>   libavformat 53. 24. 2 / 53. 24. 2
>   libavdevice 53. 4. 0 / 53. 4. 0
>   libavfilter 2. 53. 0 / 2. 53. 0
>   libswscale 2. 1. 0 / 2. 1. 0
>   libpostproc 51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
>   Input #0, matroska,webm, from >'/home/admin/clip/files/conversion_queue/1378484580dae10.mkv':
>   Duration: 00:02:17.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 591 kb/s
>   Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 554x312 [SAR 1:1 DAR 277:156], 25 fps, 25 >tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
>   Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
>   Unknown encoder 'libfaac'
>   Failed to stat file /home/admin/clip/files/videos/1378484580dae10.flv!
>   Failed to stat file /home/admin/clip/files/videos/1378484580dae10.flv!
>
> Unknown file details - Unable to get output video details using FFMPEG
>
> Time Took : 0.0814 seconds
>
> conversion_status : failed

so my version is 0.9.2 why it's not working it's writing Unknown encoder 'libfaac' Failed to stat file what I need someone to learn me how to get this this "libfaac" by using ssh on centos os please and if you can give me any site so I can improve my self with dealing with ffmpeg on my VPS also I will be grateful.

Comment: what linux distro are you using on your server? and what version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- go to your admin area of clip-bucket
- then website configurations in Stats and ...
- then Uploading and conversion settings tab
- then Video conversion tab in the bottom
- then change Audio Codec from `libfaac` to `aac -strict -2`
- then update  settings

Answer (score 0):

`Unknown encoder *libfaac*` is a pretty clear message. It tries to convert your movie with an encoder that is not supported by your build of ffmpeg.

You will have to add support for this to ffmpeg.

Either recompile ffmpeg with a changed configuration, or download the required library as a a package. A quick DuckDuckgo search on `libaac cenOS` showed several places from where you can download it, including [this source](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/linuxtech-x86_64/libfaac-devel-1.28-3.el6.x86_64.rpm.html).

Comment: # rpm -qa | grep faac
faac-devel-1.28-6.el5
libfaac0-1.28-6.el5
faac-1.28-6.el5

Comment: What happens when you log into your VPS and manually run the commands?

Comment: i don't know really but this is what i found after run this commend>ls \n091                           kloxo-install.zip
bin                           libavcodec53-0.8.14-54.el5.i386.rpm
ffmpeg-0.9.2-55.el5.i386.rpm  libavutil51-0.9.2-55.el5.i386.rpm
ffmpegauto                    libtheoradec1-1.1.1-13.el5.i386.rpm
ffmpeg_build                  libtheoraenc1-1.1.1-13.el5.i386.rpm
ffmpeg_sources                tmp
ffpresets                     xvidcore
kloxo-install                 xvidcore-1.3.2.tar.gz
kloxo-installer.sh            xvidcore-1.3.2.tar.gz.1